# Howto - setup a filter in sharppcap?

Tags: filter, sniffer, sharppcap

i'm using the [sharppcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) library and try to setup a filter. 
My goal is to setup a filter that only add packets from one ip adress and not the whole amount of data of any ip and tcp packets. i had tried the whireshark notation...

```
device = CaptureDeviceList.Instance[itemIndex];
device.Open();
device.Filter = "ip.src=10.0.0.1 and tcp"; // doesn't work - only "ip and tcp" works
```

does anybody know how to configure the filters for this library ? :-)

thanks a lot :-)

Best Regards
           Jan

Answer (score 2):

SharpPcap is a frontend for libpcap/winpcap so any filter you use has to be in a format that libpcap/winpcap understand. At this time no additional processing is performed by SharpPcap.

I believe the same filter syntax is used across libpcap/winpcap/tcpdump and wireshark.

Try something like:

"tcp and host 172.18.5.4"
[From here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters)

Chris

SharpPcap author

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string mac = "00-AA-00-AA-00-AA";
string filter =String.Format("((tcp and ip) or udp) and ether src host {0}", mac);
```